# 'UIImageView+AFNetworking.h' file not found

Tags: ios, import, installation, afnetworking

I'm learning Objective C and doing some practice iOS following some tutorial. They quickly mention the use of AFNetworking and how to use it however after hours of frustration and roaming the internet I can not get it to work. I've included the AFNetworking files and `#import "AFNetworking.h"` works but `#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"` gives the error

> 'UIImageView+AFNetworking.h' file not found

What could I be doing wrong? The tutorial i'm following might be outdated. I've simply downloaded the latest version from github, then in Xcode via File>Add Files I added the folder containing the files (I used the "Copy items if needed" and "Create groups" options).

I've attached a picture. Maybe that can give some clarification.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another directory of files for UIKit support that is part of the AFNetworking source code. Just add them to your project like you did above.

[AFNetworking Repository (UIKit)](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking)

Comment: Oh yea, didn't even see that map. Works now. Is this now the way to do this? Was there a reason they separated it? Or does something like merging 2 header files no longer work?

Comment: I could speculate that some folks wanted to use the core functionality of AFNetworking, but did not need the UIKit stuff. Leaving that part out may also allow it to work with OS X, not sure.